# No WiFi connection & wireless card is Intel 7265

Tags: networking

After executing dmesg | grep iwl I got the following

---

```
ajay@ajay-HP-ENVY-x360-m6-Convertible:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    7.380746] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    7.656699] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.657559] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.032821] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.13.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.231836] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    8.232167] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    8.232610] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    8.320209] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    8.339011] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
[   29.034771] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   29.035221] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   29.097485] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   29.097928] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   34.748671] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   34.749440] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   34.811700] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   34.812143] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[14461.349721] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 arc4 iwlmvm(OE) intel_rapl uvcvideo mac80211(OE) x86_pkg_temp_thermal hid_multitouch hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_rotation hid_sensor_incl_3d videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops hid_sensor_trigger videobuf2_core intel_powerclamp v4l2_common coretemp videodev industrialio_triggered_buffer acer_wmi kfifo_buf hp_wmi sparse_keymap industrialio snd_hda_codec_hdmi media kvm btusb hid_sensor_iio_common snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic btrtl snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec btbcm snd_soc_rt5640 snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul snd_seq_midi ghash_clmulni_intel iwlwifi(OE) aesni_intel snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 lrw btintel snd_soc_rl6231 gf128mul glue_helper bluetooth snd_soc_core ablk_helper
ajay@ajay-HP-ENVY-x360-m6-Convertible:~$
```

---

And also the following after running rfkill list all

```
ajay@ajay-HP-ENVY-x360-m6-Convertible:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Please advise further instructions to be executed

Comment: According to [this wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi), Intel® Wireless 7265 is supported since kernel version 3.13 that is included in 14.04 release. Many users asking the same here, so type "Intel 7625" in the search bar located at top right of this site and start looking for any available answers.

Answer (score 0):

Support for your device is supposed to be in Kernel 4.2, which is included with Ubuntu 15.10.  You could either try Ubuntu 15.10 (15.04 is going end-of-life soon) or you could try to upgrade the 14.04 kernel to version 4.2.  Of the two, I would suggest using Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 0):

14.04 has longer support (5 years) so if you're keeping it around for awhile it's probably a better idea.  As for the wifi adapter, i've found that even if the wireless adapter isn't working initially, if you install the OS and update it through Ethernet it should fix your problem.  I can't stress the updating part enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/801120/10715); The acer-wmi module is conflicting so it has to be blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `acer_wmi` in `lsmod`:

```
sudo lsmod | grep acer
```

If you find it, you can try unloading it:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
```